# Mapbox GL Map Distortion on Android Chrome When Container Width Exceeds 1650px

Tags: javascript, mapbox-gl-js

I'm facing an issue with Mapbox GL JS, specifically with its rendering on the Chrome browser for Android. The map works fine on Chrome for both Windows and macOS. However, on Android, I observe a distortion when the map container's width exceeds 1650px.

Issue Description:

- Environment: Chrome Browser on Android (latest version)
- Mapbox GL JS Version: 3.0 (also observed in other versions)
- Expected Behavior: The map should render consistently across all platforms without any distortion.
- Actual Behavior: On Android Chrome, when the map container's width is set to more than 1650px, the map displays with distortion.
  To better illustrate this issue, here are two screenshots:

1. Normal Rendering (Width <= 1650px):[Map displays correctly on Android Chrome at or below 1650px width.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fEGqi.png)
2. Distorted Rendering (Width > 1650px):[Map distortion is visible on Android Chrome when width exceeds 1650px.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BPO9R.jpg)

I've also created a Codepen example to demonstrate this issue:
[https://codepen.io/cylqinsmoon/pen/Rwvdbyv]

Attempts to Resolve:

- Ensured that the Chrome browser is updated on the Android device.
- Checked for CSS styles that might affect rendering, but found none.
- The issue is consistent across various Android devices and versions.
  Questions:

1. Has anyone encountered similar rendering issues with Mapbox GL JS on Android's Chrome browser?
2. Are there known compatibility issues with Mapbox GL JS that might cause this?
3. Could this be related to device resolutions or pixel densities on Android?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered a similar issue and found a solution that might work for this scenario. This approach is inspired by a commit in MapLibre GL JS ([04eebcc](https://github.com/maplibre/maplibre-gl-js/commit/04eebccac44e621e2f8250fb3b193809eba1fbad)), but remember to account for the differences between MapboxGL and MaplibreGL.

1. **Adjusting the Painter's Resize Method**: The `pixelRatio` parameter seems to be missing in the `painter`'s `resize` method. Modify it to include `pixelRatio`:

   ```js
   resize(width, height, pixelRatio) {
       pixelRatio = pixelRatio || browser.devicePixelRatio || 1;
       // ... rest of the resize method
   }
   ```
2. **Updates in Map.js**: The `map.js` file requires several additions:

   - Implement `_overridePixelRatio` and `pixelRatio` parameters.
   - Include `_containerDimensions`, `_getClampedPixelRatio`, and `getPixelRatio` methods, which are currently missing.
3. **Canvas Resize Modification**: Just like in the `painter`'s resize method, `_resizeCanvas` should also handle `pixelRatio`:

   ```js
   _resizeCanvas(width, height, pixelRatio) {
       // ... handle resizing with pixelRatio
   }
   ```
4. **MapLibre's Resize Method**: Note that MapLibre's `resize` method uses `this._requestedCameraState?.resize(width, height);` It's not present in minemap, but its absence hasn't led to any issues so far.

These changes should help address the distortion issue on Android Chrome for containers wider than 1650px. It's advisable to test these modifications across different environments to confirm their effectiveness.